# Laravel - Mail::send() How to pass data (in array format) to email html and send it

Tags: php, laravel, html-email, sendmail

I am trying to pass the value from the request, which is stored as an array, to an email in html format before sending.

```
$data = array('email' => $request->get('email'), 'name' => $request->get('name'));
    Mail::send('emails.email', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->subject('Hello world!');
        $message->to($data['email'], $data['name']);
    });
```

This is my email html format file in ***email.blade.php***

```
<h2>HELLO YOU HAVE A NEW EVENT!</h2>
<h3>TO {{$name}}</h3>
<h4>See more details .... <a href="http://localhost:8000/event" target="_blank">Events</a></h4>
```

But it appears that the html file does not receive the variable ($name) that was sent

How to pass data (in array format) to email html?

I tried sending without the $ name variable. It appears that there is no problem. Everything goes smoothly But I really need to use variables Please help me

I can use $name if use this code

```
$data['name'] = "Guest";
    Mail::send('emails.email', $data, function ($message) {
        $message->to('email@gmail.com', 'name')
                ->subject('topic');
    });
```

Why?

Comment: In mail class should build method and in build method return $this->view() maybe help it to you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#view-data via the `with` method might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
Mail::send('emails.email', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->subject('Hello world!');
        $message->to($data['email'], $data['name']);
});
```

You're passing a `data` variable, not `name` (`['data' => $data]`). So get the name from that array:

```
<h2>HELLO YOU HAVE A NEW EVENT!</h2>
<h3>TO {{ $data['name'] }}</h3>
```

Or pass the `$data` variable directly so that you will have access to all its values as separate variables:

```php
Mail::send('emails.email', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->subject('Hello world!');
        $message->to($data['email'], $data['name']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to declare the variable in your mail class like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MailForm extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $fullname;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($fullname)
    {
        //
        $this->fullname     = $fullname;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('sendmail');
    }
}
```

then in your view you can now call the variable

```
{{ $fullname }}
```

dont forget to call the mail class and mail facades in your controller like:

```
use App\Mail\MailForm;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```